# Django AWS RDS environment variables not setting in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I'm using Amazon Linux 2 in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance to host my Django web server. When using SSHing into my environment, I cannot run manage.py commands because `os.environ` doesn't contain environment variables for my RDS db. So when in my `settings.py` file I try to access the database like so:

```
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
    }
}
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'home',
            'USER': '',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

It thinks I am still on localhost and it gives me an error. How do I get around this? Is there a way to load in my RDS environment variables via the `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment` command or is there another way that doesn't require SSH?

Update:

Based on @Marcin's answer, I used the following commands in my local terminal to SSH into my EC2 instance and manually make updates:

```
eb ssh
```

(Enter your password when prompted)

```
source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate
export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
```

To get into the correct directory where you files are:

```
cd /var/app/current
```

Now you can run:

```
python manage.py <your command>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run `manage.py` through your `.ebextentions` config file, but need to first to **load your environment variables**.

Since you haven't provided any config file, I can just exemplify what you could attempt for EB platform based on **Amazon Linux 2** (for AL1 it is different):

```
container_commands:
  10_run_manage_py:
    command: |
      export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
      source $PYTHONPATH/activate
      python ./manage.py <your command>
```

The above is example only, thus you would need to adjust it to your setup.

Comment: Do I need to change anything on the export line? I'm getting two errors in the AWS log that are causing the build to fail

Comment: @AdvayRatan Can you update the question with your `10_run_manage_py` and the error messages.

Comment: @AdvayRatan Can you also check `cfn-init-cmd.log` and find part related to execution `10_run_manage_py`.

Comment: I used your commands to manually SSH into my instance and make the necessary changes. I think I got it from here. Thanks a lot.